# Exception handling with lambda/linq statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, lambda

I have the following statement that I am trying to use a try-catch block with

```
var val= db.shops.where(x=>×.id==ID).Select (a=>a.address).First();
```

I tried following but has many issues won't even compile.

```
var val=db.shops.Where(x=> 
  {
    try 
    {
        (x.Id==ID).Select(a=>a.address).First();
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
      return ex;
    }
  }
```

Please let me know how can I handle the exception in this statement Thanks.
Note: writing this question from mobile phone can't format code. Apologize for it.

Comment: Put the `try` around the original line

Comment: Why not wrap the whole statement in a try/catch?

Comment: By the way, you can format code on a phone.  For a code block, put 4 spaces before every line of code.  For inline code, put a `backquote` (aka a _tick_) around the code.  On my phone, I can see a backquote if I hold down the single quote character

Comment: `Try-Catch` is not meant to catch compiler exceptions- If the code cannot compile, it will not see the `try-catch` block

Comment: `that I am trying to use try catch block with` <= I am guessing you probably meant to write `FirstOrDefault` as the exception is that there are no matches?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Flydog. This is first time I am handling exception the expressions any help in code will be appreciated

Comment: Why did you tag this as C# 4.0?

Comment: A `try-catch` and a `Select` inside a `Where`? The condition would have to be returned with `return x.Id==ID;` and the `Select` would have to follow the `Where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `try` around your original statement:

```
try
{
   var val= db.shops.where(x=>×.id==ID).Select (a=>a.address).First();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return ex; //I assume the return type here is wrong.  Maybe return null?
}
```

However, there's nothing about that line that should require a `try/catch`.  Try this:

```
var val= db.shops.where(x=>×.id==ID).Select(a=>a.address).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if there are no results.

Answer (score 2):

Everything inside brackets (`{ }`) need to have 'regular' block syntax, so return is required here:

```
...
.Where
(x=> 
  {
    try 
    {
        return (x.Id == ID);
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
      throw;
    }
  }
)
.Select(a=>a.address)
.First(); // Or FirstOrDefault if you expect this statement to yield no result.
```

As you  see, the `Where` is more like a regular statement now. The `Select` is moved to outside the `Where`. If you need exception handling in there, you have to do the same as in the `Where` block now. Last, `return ex` is probably meant to be `throw ex`, which should be `throw` in this case to preserve call stack.

Comment: Correct answer to question as asked also unlikely to help OP as they seem to query some sort of database and try inside query will not work.

Answer (score 2):

> ...that I am trying to use try catch block with

I am guessing you probably meant to write `FirstOrDefault` based on where you want the `try/catch`. In the sample code you have provided I see no reason to try to make a catch block into one of the lambda statements. The best thing to do would be to simply use FirstOrDefault as that is the reason why you might get an exception in the code shown.

```
var address = db.shops.FirstOrDefault(x => ×.id == ID)?.Address;
if(address == null)
  // nothing was found or address is null, do something else
```

Or similar code closer to what you had without my "optimization"

```
var shop = db.shops.FirstOrDefault(x => ×.id == ID);
if(shop == null) {
  // nothing was found, do something else
}
var address = shop.address;
```

The other reason not to use try/catch is that it can't be translated into SQL and the variable name `db` which is the container for the `shops` collection which leads me to believe you are using EF or some other ORM. So even if you were to fix the syntax and your code with added try/catch block compiles you will get a run time error later when you execute the lambda.